# Recieving errors when connecting Spotify API to PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, spotify

I'm just looking for some help with this error.
So i am trying to connect to the spotify API with this function:

```
(Artistname as text) =>
let
    Source = Json.Document(
        Web.Contents("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" & Artistname & "&type=artist&limit=1",
            [Headers = [Authorization = "Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", 
                        Accept = "application/json",
                        #"Content-Type" = "application/json"]
            ])
    )
in
    Source
```

I have a list of artists and I want to create a new column "artist_data" with the artist info from the API. It runs but the artist_data column appears with with this error instead of records:

**
Expression.Error: The 'Authorization' header is only supported when connecting anonymously. These headers can be used with all authentication types: Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Cache-Control, Content-Type, If-Modified-Since, Prefer, Range, Referer
**

However when I change to anonymous I get this error and it doesnt run:

**
We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again. **

Any help would be much appreciated. Maybe there is a way I can authenticate else where and still remain anon?

I have tried inserting my client ID and Sercret in the Access Web Content however I recieve the Expression.Error. I'll also note that I have been able to retreive the artist info from one artist as a test and I only run into thsi issue when I use the function to interate through the list of aritst that I have.